# how does viso2_ros work? (monocular odometry)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I'm testing viso2_ros package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros), in particularly, VisualOdometryMono class and its functions.
Does anyone provide me any information about monocular odometry algorithm working?
Is it based on "A Robust Visual Odometry and Precipice Detection System Using Consumer-grade Monocular Vision" written by Campbell,Sukthankar,Nourbakhsh,Pahwa (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1570639).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41944/how-does-viso2_ros-work?-(monocular-odometry)/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-08-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The autor of the original library is Andreas Geiger from KIT. His webpage with information and related publications can be found here: http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libviso2.html

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1